# Third party youtube app as default on iOS 5.1.1 (iPad1,1, jailbroken)

Tags: youtube, ios, ipad, jailbreak

Is there any way to set up third party youtube app as default on iOS 5.1.1 (iPad1,1) i.e. ProTube?

I've heard about TubeSelector, but it's only available for higher iOS versions.

(By "Default" I mean ability to open youtube URLs from mail or from sites.)

N.B. The reason is: native YouTube.app by Apple is not supported by youtube servers anymore. And it recommends to upgrade (what is impossible - as far as iOS 5.1.1 is the latest OS for iPad1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking "Youtube" from Parental Controls might be a workaround to open youtube-URLs in Safari. It's pretty close, at least playback is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Just install any good third party youtube app from the app store, like Jasmine or Youtube Pro etc... Or since your iPad is jailbroken install a tweak called: older version of the app (if you can't find it on cidya try google), and find a version of official youtube app by google that supports ios 5.x.x

Comment: The problem is not to find actual supported youtube app - it is already installed. The problem is to set up this app as default - to open any URL associated with youtube with this app. Right now it is native Apple app (which is not supported by youtube servers) is default app. And it is useless an malicious - it opens any youtube URL but cannot play it. So, the question is: is analogue of TubeSelector for iOS 5.1.1 exists?